# ImportError("Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")

Tags: python, fluidsynth

I have installed fluidsynth version 2.0.5 and am using it in mingus. However, when i ran the code

```
from mingus.midi import fluidsynth
```

It return this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rudiherrig 1 2/Desktop/pythonstuff/musicExp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mingus.midi import fluidsynth
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mingus/midi/fluidsynth.py", line 37, in <module>
    from mingus.midi import pyfluidsynth as fs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mingus/midi/pyfluidsynth.py", line 41, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")
ImportError: Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.
```

I find this quite confusing as i have fluidsynth installed. Any ideas on how to fix this?
Edit: I found a file called fluidsynth_dll.dsp in my library so i dont know why it is returning this error.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am also facing this problem.

Comment: I fixed this by saving the libfluidsynth-3.dll and its dependencies (a bunch of other .dlls) into the same directory as the fluidsynth.exe (this is the install path per cmd).

Answer (score 3):

I met with the same problem and resolved in the following way:

0. I have Mac system with M1 chip, Ventura OS. I homebrewed fluidsynth. As a result, the find_library only couldn't find the library in homebrew dictionary.
1. Find the path of fluidsynth.
   In terminal, `run brew --prefix fluidsynth`
   My result is `/opt/homebrew/opt/fluid-synth`

   The path of fluidsynth then would be `/opt/homebrew/opt/fluid-synth/lib/libfluidsynth.dylib`

2. Add that path to python file.
   When you get the error message, it guides you to the path of the error-raised py, such as
   `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mingus/midi/pyfluidsynth.py", line 41, in <module> raise ImportError("Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")`

   In the Finder, Go - Go to folder.., and go to the path, then open the file.

    In the editor, find the lines

```
lib = (
    find_library("fluidsynth")
    or find_library("libfluidsynth")
    or find_library("libfluidsynth-1")
)
```

3. After that line, add a new line `lib = '...path...'` with the path from step 1.

This will solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libfluidsynth.dll`

1. Download precompiled DLL from: https://zdoom.org/downloads#Support
2. If you use 64x version rename file from `libfluidsynth64.dll` to `libfluidsynth.dll`
3. Place it into `C:\Windows\System32`

You can also compile it by yourself using GitHub project